# submit a disabled combo box

Tags: java, validation, struts

Using Struts 1.2 In Jsp page a combo box is set as disabled and I tried to submit the page with errors. html:error is shown, but the combo box is not loading the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Disable property cannot be loaded in action form .

Suggestion : The property can be maintained as hidden values

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the html fields before submiting the form. Either you can use prototype JS enable() method to enable all the fields of the form or you can write your own method.